CANVASJS create stepArea Chart with Timeframe Values
So here is my Problem. I have a Database Request which extract me 2 dates.
1st A Target Date $timestamp
2nd A Latest Start Date $latest_start (which is Target Date - Time to go)
while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
{
    
# Show only if a ReadOut is defined
if ($row2['ReadOut'] != '') {
# If not Run put Time to 0
if ($row2['Done'] == '')        { $time_done2 = 0;}     else {$time_done2 = $row2['Done'];}
# Calculate Time To go
$time_to_go2=$row2['ReadOut']-$time_done2;  
@$time_to_go_overall=$time_to_go_overall+$time_to_go2;  

if (!empty($row2['TargetDate'])){
        $target2=$row2['TargetDate']->format('d.m.Y');
}

$timestamp = strtotime($target2);
$latest_start = ($timestamp - ($time_to_go2*3600));


Additionally i fetch from another database a Number Value $nr_of_products_on_pcb2
$pcb_query2=("SELECT DISTINCT NR_OF_PRODUCTS FROM $db_pcb2 WHERE PCB_NAME LIKE '$pcb_name2'");
#echo $pcb_query.'<br/>';
$pcb_result2=mysqli_query($connection2, $pcb_query2);
$pcb2 = mysqli_fetch_array($pcb_result2);
@$nr_of_products_on_pcb2=$pcb2['NR_OF_PRODUCTS'];

So now i have the following Variables within the loop:
echo 'Latest Start Date: '.$latest_start.'-';
echo 'Time To Go: '.$sec_to_go.'-';
echo 'Target End Date: '.$timestamp.' - ';
echo 'Nr. of PCBs: '.$nr_of_pcbs2.' <br>  ';

Now i want to plot a stepped Area Chart with Canvasjs, where the Value will be increased by the Nr. of PCBs on the Latest_start Date ($latest_start) and decreased by the same Nr. of PCBs  on the Target End Date ($timestamp).
At the End i want to push this overall number to a stepped Area Chart in CANVASJS to plot it
array_push($dataPoints, array("x"=> @$timestamp2, "y"=> $nr_of_pcbs_overall, "toolTipContent"=> $label));

Since the Latest Start and the Target End Date always within 1 Loop i currently don't know how to generate the step Value
Latest Start Date: 1673218800-Time To Go: 6393600-Target End Date: 1679612400 - Nr. of PCBs: 16
Latest Start Date: 1719468000-Time To Go: 3600000-Target End Date: 1723068000 - Nr. of PCBs: 16
Latest Start Date: 1719468000-Time To Go: 3600000-Target End Date: 1723068000 - Nr. of PCBs: 16
Latest Start Date: 1719468000-Time To Go: 3600000-Target End Date: 1723068000 - Nr. of PCBs: 16
.....
Appreciating any Idea.
Best Thanks in advance
I tried to create a loop to calculate the Current Overall of NR_of_PCBs

Do you have same Nr. of PCBs for every timeframe? Also, are you looking for Gantt type of chart for your data?
